# phpmyadmin styling totally broken. Error: Can't find stylesheet to import

Tags: sass, phpmyadmin

phpmyadmin doesn't load any stylesheets at all. Login and URLs send responses but otherwise unusable [how pma home looks right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42DLf.png)

I'm on archlinux. Installed from pacman and no issues for a long time. last update is 5.2.1. Recently tried custom themes and specifically changing accent color for metro. and as per https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/16969

```
mv themes/metro/css/theme.css themes/metro/css/win-theme.css
mv themes/metro/css/mono-theme.css themes/metro/css/theme.css
```

Couldn't get it to work. also tried running npm install, npm install -g sass and some combination of install/uninstalls and renaming css files. Couldn't get it themes to change but phpmyadmin worked. I gave up on theme colors.

Today I get a

```
 Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.
 @import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 themes/bootstrap/scss/_bootstrap.scss 3:9 @import.
```

I tried installing yarn and running sudo yarn install (sudo because phpmyadmin is installed on /usr/share/webapps/phpMyAdmin on my distro and would give permission errors otherwise. but sudo yarn install gives me:

```
rtlcss: invalid config file.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

The error persists.even uninstalling everything (I even tried deleting the phpMyAdmin folder just in case) and reinstalling. I don't know what else to try. I just want basic phpmyadmin to work. See image. What can I do?

PS: I've noticed "sudo npm install bootstrap" does create a /node_modules/bootstrap/scss/ folder but there is no /node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions folder inside. Am I doing something real basic wrong?